# How to use AWS S3 health check method provided by AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks library

Tags: c#, .net-core, health-check

AWS S3 health check is one of the built-in health check services provided by .NET Core. It is available in `AspNetCore.HealthChecks.Aws` nuget package and presumably can be used like the following code snippet:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddHealthChecks().AddS3("WHAT SHOULD GO HERE");
}
```

After searching a lot, I could not find an example or a sample displaying its usage, even on Microsoft's website.

This is a ASP.NET Core Web API project written in c#.

Comment: I've reverted your question to its original form, as your changes had changed the scope of your question, invalidating the (correct) answer I have provided. Note that `bo => bo = new S3BucketOptions { AccessKey = "bob"; }` (your code) and `bo => bo.AccessKey = "bob"` do very different things.

Comment: I've created a [demo](https://rextester.com/TQDO29633) to show you the difference between what I'm doing here (`bucketOptions => bucketOptions.AccesKey = "hello"`) and what you were doing in your revised question code (`bucketOptions => bucketOptions = new S3bucketOptions { AccessKey = "hello" };`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For starters, `AspNetCore.HealthChecks.Aws` is a [third party library](https://github.com/xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks) and certainly isn't provided by Microsoft.

Looking at the [code for the `AddS3` extension method](https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks/blob/50594f0643515e83f9bf6ce864f9594bf980b865/src/HealthChecks.Aws.S3/DependencyInjection/S3HealthCheckBuilderExtensions.cs), it seems that you're expected to provide a configuration for `S3BucketOptions`:

```
services.AddHealthChecks().AddS3(bucketOptions => 
{
    bucketOptions.AccessKey = "hello";
    // etc
});
```

[Source for S3BucketOptions](https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks/blob/50594f0643515e83f9bf6ce864f9594bf980b865/src/HealthChecks.Aws.S3/S3BucketOptions.cs)

Comment: I update my question and made it more descriptive, with the actual exception.

Comment: @user1451111 Please try my answer. Your updated code isn't equivalent to this.

Comment: IS there any similar API provided by AWS?

Comment: @DixitSingla Do you mean health checks originating from AWS? It sounds like there might be from having a quick Google - I certainly saw something mentioned for ELB - but I haven't used AWS in some time so I can't confirm.

Comment: We are adding aws service for s3 using iam role.In the healthcheck we need to check if the client is successfully created. the one provided by `AspNetCore` we need to pass the secret keys which we don't want to do. I have googled it but did not find the any. May be I am searching the wrong way.

Comment: We are adding aws service for s3 using iam role.In the health check we need to check if the client is successfully created. The one provided by `AspNetCore` required to pass the secret keys which we don't want to do. I have googled it but did not find the any. May be I am searching the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide following configurations:

```
.AddS3(o => 
{ 
   o.AccessKey = "Your Access Key"; 
   o.SecretKey = "Your Secret Key";
   o.BucketName = "Your Bucket Name";
   o.S3Config = new();
});
```